# Merge git commit history

Tags: git

After merge all commits into one (for rewrite git log history) on local machine (this operation was succesfull) I have a notice after command `git status`

```
Your branch and 'origin/master' have diverged,
# and have 1 and 8 different commits each, respectively.
```

These 8 commits are those commits that I have been merged into one.
I tried to do `git push --force origin master` and the result is

```
Compressing objects: 100% (9924/9924), done.
Writing objects: 100% (21454/21454), 24.68 MiB | 2.95 MiB/s, done.
Total 21454 (delta 8595), reused 20826 (delta 8591)
remote: error: denying non-fast-forward refs/heads/master (you should pull first)
To http://somesite.com/gitproject.git
! [remote rejected] master -> master (non-fast-forward)
error: failed to push some refs to 'http://somesite.com/gitproject.git'
```

And branches remained diverged.
And I think if I'll do `git pull` then all git commits history that have been merged appear again on local machine.

To cut a long story short how can I push local git commits history into origin branch?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like the problem here is like some commits have been pushed to origin from someone while you made your own commits locally.

So your history in git looks like something like this.

```
*   d993799 Commit 1
*   caa12d6 Commit 2
|\
| * e38fecc Your Commit 
|
*   29158f8 Commit 3
```

Now, you have two options, do a Merge or a Rebase

```
git merge origin/master
```

or

```
git rebase origin/master
```

*Pro Tip after you do commits locally when you are ready to push into origin do a* `git pull --rebase` *doing that is going to pull the latest version of origin and then it is going to try to update your changes*

Some Awesome url:
http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Branching-Rebasing

Comment: "Now, you have two options" doesn't explain why you'd choose one option or another or what the effect of choosing each option would be.